# Android Studio: Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jack-compiler

So, I using Android Studio 2.2 stable version now, I get following error on running app after update studio to 2.2 version:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
> java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

this is my app -> build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.proba"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        jackOptions {
            additionalParameters("jack.incremental": true)
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        incremental true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:viewanimator:1.0.4'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
}
```

Comment: Removing additionalParameters("jack.incremental": true) fixes the problem for me. I filed a bug report here. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223658

Comment: Thanks you @mystilleef I removed incremental flag and support-v4:24.2.1 then works fine

Answer (score 3):

Make it to **"true"** instead of true.

```
additionalParameters("jack.incremental": "true")
```

I hope this should work.

Comment: @mr.boyfox then how did you solve this issue?, can you please explain about ?